# DocuSign API - How to implement “Needs to View”

Tags: docusignapi

We want to add recipient needs to view before other recipients can sign.

How can we implement Needs to View option in RestApi of docusign ?

Regards,
Dishant

Answer (score 5):

The eSignature API calls these recipients [Certified Delivery](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#certified-delivery-recipient) recipients.
You do everything else the same, but these recipients cannot or should not have tab (Signing elements) as they only need to view, but not sign.
The JSON looks like this:

```
{"certifiedDeliveries":[{"routingOrder":1,"name":"Inbar Gazit","email":"email@email.email","roleName":"","note":"","status":"created","templateAccessCodeRequired":null,"deliveryMethod":"email","recipientId":"1"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you Inbar Gazit, your answer helped me a lot for this rare question. Also I found a link that has some helpful detail https://apps.kennesaw.edu/files/pr_app_uni_cdoc/doc/sending_envelopes_in_docusign.pdf